# Localized XIB not showing all IBActions, outlet & images

Tags: iphone, localization, arabic

i m getting a problem with my localized xib.
I have created english version xib first, then made them localized, & added other localization.
it works fine in app also.
But when i open other language xib with IB, i m unable to get all outlets & IBActions.
It seems like it is taking only those one that were present when i created the localized file, & not showing newly added one.

Does file not getting updated?

Note : My other team member done the same thing & they don't have problem.
i also tried to removed & created all new localized file then also no change.

I m unable to identify the problem, i m stuck on this problem & cannot proceed with further development.

Please help .. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have Xibs in different languages, they don't get updated automatically when you change the English one.

Instead, you should either merge the new changes using `ibtool` (type `man ibtool` in Terminal to learn its options), or use a dedicated application like [iLocalize](http://www.arizona-software.ch/ilocalize/).

In general, it can be quite an issue to update all the localizations all the time and sometimes large changes can't be merged well automatically. You need to be careful about that.